# Calculate two records and join them in the same MySQL row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that contains the data of an access control of employees, entry and exits from the office in different rows.
The output is based on a query in a date and time range example 
`ac_date >= '2018-05-12' AND ac_date <= '2018-05-13' AND ac_time >='08:00:00' AND ac_time <= '13:00:00']`  
**Table AC**

```
CREATE TABLE `AC` (
  `employee` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ac_date` date NOT NULL,
  `ac_time` time NOT NULL,
  `ac_event` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  KEY `index2` (`employee`,`ac_date`,`ac_time`,`ac_event`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Employee     ac_date        ac_time     ac_event
2032        2018-05-12      08:52:00        1
2032        2018-05-12      11:39:33        0
2032        2018-05-12      11:48:06        1
2032        2018-05-12      11:52:54        0
2032        2018-05-12      11:59:54        1
2032        2018-05-12      12:23:40        0
2032        2018-05-13      08:34:43        1
2032        2018-05-13      09:02:25        0
2032        2018-05-13      09:12:16        1
2032        2018-05-13      11:45:21        0
2032        2018-05-13      12:50:40        1
2032        2018-05-13      12:52:16        0
```

**Where ac_ event = 1 is the input and ac event = 0 is the output.**

I need to make a query that shows the data in the same row (Entry / Exit) to then take the time the employee lasts outside the office.
Ej:

**Output for the first block:**

```
Employee    entry_date   exit_date      entry_date   exit_date  duration 
2032        2018-05-12   2018-05-12     08:52:00     11:39:33   02:47:33
```

I was able to get the result by doing a query with the same table, but I have duplicate data, so I have to resort to the group by [ac_date, ac_time]. I do not know if the way I'm trying is the right one, so I'd like to see an expert's solution. Thank you!

**Update:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f36f/3

Comment: Please add query you have written already

Comment: How do you want to handle row 3,4,5 and 6 as they belong to same employee and on same date?  My query will consider first login and last logout of an employee for a day and calculate the time difference. i.e. one row per employee per day

Answer (score 2):

This is a simplified version of your original query:

```
select AC.employee, AC.ac_date, AC.ac_time,
   min(AC2.ac_time) as exit_time,
   timediff(min(AC2.ac_time), AC.ac_time)
from AC
left join AC as AC2
  on AC2.ac_date = AC.ac_date 
 and AC2.ac_time > ac.ac_time
 and AC2.ac_event = 0
where AC.ac_event = 1
  AND AC.ac_date >= '2018-05-11'
  AND AC.ac_date <= '2018-05-13'
  AND AC.ac_time >= '00:00:00'
  AND AC.ac_time <= '23:59:00'
group by AC.employee, AC.ac_date, AC.ac_time
order by AC.employee, AC.ac_date, AC.ac_time
;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d4bb4/8)

But no matter how you write it, it's always a kind of non-equi-join (i.e. not based on `=`) and performance might be bad without matching indexes.

Btw, if this was MariaDB or MySQL 8 it would be a simple task for LAG/LEAD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @dnoeth
as I said before even though your answer is with the solution
The optimizer does not consider it efficient.
This method considers it more optimal, the cost is much lower.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f36f/3

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    TIMEDIFF(exit_time,entry_time) as duration
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Employee, 
            ac_date as entry_date,
            ac_date as exit_date,
            MIN(CASE WHEN ac_event=1 THEN ac_time END) entry_time,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ac_event=0 THEN ac_time END) exit_time
        FROM
            AC
        GROUP BY 
            Employee,
            ac_date
    ) as t
```

Comment: This will just give one entry per `employee, ac_date`. I think the OP actually wants to calculate the duration between *consecutive* entry / exit points. Judging from the sample data provided we can have multiple  entry - exit pairs for a single day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use correlated subqueries to get entry / exit pairs:

```
SELECT employee, ac_date AS entry_date,
       (SELECT ac_date 
       FROM AC AS i
       WHERE i.ac_event = 0 
             AND i.employee = t.employee 
             AND i.ac_date >= t.ac_date 
             AND i.ac_time >= t.ac_time
       ORDER BY i.ac_date, i.ac_time LIMIT 1) AS exit_date,
       ac_time AS entry_time,       
       (SELECT ac_time
       FROM AC AS i
       WHERE i.ac_event = 0 
             AND i.employee = t.employee 
             AND i.ac_date >= t.ac_date 
             AND i.ac_time >= t.ac_time
       ORDER BY i.ac_date, i.ac_time LIMIT 1) AS exit_time       
FROM AC AS t
WHERE t.ac_date BETWEEN '2018-05-12' AND '2018-05-13' AND t.ac_event = 1;
```

**Output:**

```
employee entry_date  exit_date   entry_time  exit_time
-------------------------------------------------------
2032     2018-05-12  2018-05-12  08:52:00    11:39:33
2032     2018-05-12  2018-05-12  11:48:06    11:52:54
2032     2018-05-12  2018-05-12  11:59:54    12:23:40
2032     2018-05-13  2018-05-13  08:34:43    09:02:25
2032     2018-05-13  2018-05-13  09:12:16    11:45:21
2032     2018-05-13  2018-05-13  12:50:40    12:52:16
```

Then you can use [**TIMESTAMPDIFF**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to calculate the time between each entry - exit:

```
SELECT employee, entry_date, exit_date, entry_time, exit_time, 
        SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                                  CONCAT(entry_date, ' ', entry_time), 
                                  CONCAT(exit_date, ' ', exit_time))) AS duration
FROM (
SELECT employee, ac_date AS entry_date,
       (SELECT ac_date 
       FROM AC AS i
       WHERE i.ac_event = 0 
             AND i.employee = t.employee 
             AND i.ac_date >= t.ac_date 
             AND i.ac_time >= t.ac_time
       ORDER BY i.ac_date, i.ac_time LIMIT 1) AS exit_date,
       ac_time AS entry_time,       
       (SELECT ac_time
       FROM AC AS i
       WHERE i.ac_event = 0 
             AND i.employee = t.employee 
             AND i.ac_date >= t.ac_date 
             AND i.ac_time >= t.ac_time
       ORDER BY i.ac_date, i.ac_time LIMIT 1) AS exit_time       
FROM AC AS t
WHERE t.ac_date BETWEEN '2018-05-12' AND '2018-05-13' AND t.ac_event = 1) AS x
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/759763/5)

Comment: Excellent!
The way he was using was this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f36f/3

Comment: Although the answer gives with the problem I do not know what impact it can have on a table with several thousand records. 2

Comment: Rahul's solution will give you better performance as he is using a derived table.  Remember that sub-queries (in the select) will run that query for every row returned by the initial query.

If you had 1000 rows, you would run 2000 additional queries to calculate the entry and exit time (doesn't sound like much but this is obviously a scaling problem and requires you to be more smart with your indexes if you want to maintain performance)

Comment: @Alex: Rahul's solution will give much better performance, but a totally different result, too :-)

Comment: @dnoeth that's a very good point, my bad - I'm browsing on my phone and saw derived tables vs. sub-queries.

Comment: @Giorgos
According to the execution plan of Mysql, this query although it gives the result is not the most optimal, considering that the table contains thousands of records.
The method I am using is closer to better performance.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f36f/3

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** Just rank data for every entry `employee, ac_date, ac_time` wise and exit in the separate set then join, it's the one simple way where you can use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` for the better performance if you want the records with both entry and exit

```
SELECT en.employee,  
    en.entry_date,
    ex.exit_date,
    en.entry_time,
    ex.exit_time,
TIMEDIFF(ex.exit_time, en.entry_time) as duration
FROM (
    SELECT employee,
        ac_date AS entry_date,
        ac_time AS entry_time,
        @enRank := @enRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM AC, (SELECT @enRank := 0) r
    WHERE ac_event = 1 ORDER BY employee, ac_date, ac_time) en
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT employee,
                ac_date AS exit_date,
                ac_time AS exit_time,
                @exRank := @exRank + 1 AS rank
            FROM AC, (SELECT @exRank := 0) r
            WHERE ac_event = 0 ORDER BY employee, ac_date, ac_time) ex ON ex.rank = en.rank
AND ex.employee = en.employee
WHERE en.entry_date >= '2018-05-12' AND ex.exit_date <= '2018-05-13'
ORDER BY en.entry_date
```

**OUTPUT** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/891d91/18

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a double join to the same table in order to get the exit record:

```
SELECT t1.employee, 
       t1.ac_date AS entry_date,
       t1.ac_time AS entry_time,
       t2.ac_date AS exit_date,
       t2.ac_time AS exit_time,
       SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                                  CONCAT(t1.ac_date, ' ', t1.ac_time), 
                                  CONCAT(t2.ac_date, ' ', t2.ac_time))) AS duration       

/* fetches entry records */
FROM AC AS t1       

/* fetches exit records that occur after the correlated entry record */
INNER JOIN AC AS t2 

   ON t1.employee = t2.employee AND t2.ac_event = 0
      AND CONCAT(t1.ac_date, ' ', t1.ac_time) <= CONCAT(t2.ac_date, ' ', t2.ac_time) 

/* fetches exit records that occur between t1, t2 records */
LEFT JOIN AC AS t3  
   ON t2.employee = t3.employee AND t3.ac_event = 0 
      AND CONCAT(t3.ac_date, ' ', t3.ac_time) >= CONCAT(t1.ac_date, ' ', t1.ac_time) 
      AND CONCAT(t3.ac_date, ' ', t3.ac_time) < CONCAT(t2.ac_date, ' ', t2.ac_time) 
WHERE t1.ac_date BETWEEN '2018-05-12' AND '2018-05-13' 
      AND t1.ac_event = 1 
      AND t3.employee IS NULL /* There is no record between t1 entry and t2 exit */
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/759763/6)